# How to receive the Map object from HTTPClient in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rest

This is the return type from rest end point:

```
ResponseEntity<Map<String, List<Object>>>
```

How do I receive this response from Angular side?

I tried this approach:

```
let requiredData= new Map<String, Array<Object>>();
 this.service.getMap().subscribe((mapData) => {
      requiredData= mapData;
}
```

I'm able to log this in the console properly. But the issue is whenever I try to fetch items from the map or fetch keys as below, it always returns **undefined**

```
requiredData.keys
```

Anybody know what is the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TS you can use the **RECORD** type to treat Maps.
Try the following for your case:

```
requiredData: Record<String,Object[]>;

this.service.getMap()
.subscribe((mapData: Record<String,Object[]>) => {
        this.requiredData= mapData;
      });
```

In your **service**:

```
getMap(): Observable<Record<String,Object[]>> {
      return this.http.get<Record<String,Object[]>>(
        'your end point'
      );
    }
```

To display the fetched data, try the following in your **HTML**:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let dataObject of requiredData | keyvalue">
   <p>This is the string key : {{ dataObject.key }}</p>

 <div *ngFor="let object of dataObject.value">
    <!--Replace id/name with your params-->
       {{object.id}} -  {{object.name}}
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But how do I iterate over "Record" to fetch its content?

Comment: U're welcome.I updated my answer with the HTML part.

Answer (score 0):

Default value that returns new HttpClient is Object. It automatically calls `response.json()` internally.

You can tell HttpClient what type the response will be, so:

```
this.httpClient.get<User[]>(...)
 .map((users) => {
   ...
```